# how to make the post data of http requests invisible from debugging programs

Tags: c#

i'm working on a project where i use my account to sign in to a site ( POST Method ) after the sign in the program provides what it was made for 
my question is how can i hide or make the post data (my account user and pass) hidden from the sniffing apps 
i'm afraid that anyone with http analyse app can analyse my httpwebrequests and steal my info so is there any way to do that ?

Edited

```
string referer = "http://example.com/";
        ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
        string postData = "action=login&returnpage=&login_login=user&login_password=pass";
        byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(postData);
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(referer);
        request.Method = "POST";
```

i'm trying to avoid what's in this photo

[this is a screen shot from a sniffing app after launching my app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rVAWo.png)

Comment: If you are sending account information in cleartext, a debugger against the server is the *least* of your problems.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET not in a cleartext it's combined within the postdata in ""

Comment: unclear what you are saying; but my point is that by sending a post that contains your user data in plain text, packet sniffers can easily see your site (or MitM attacks, etc). Attaching a debugger to your server is not a very common attack vector.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET what i meant string postdata = " user=..+pass=.." ; 
sniffers that's exactly what i'm trying to avoid

Comment: Instead of plain text, consider encrypted data. Build in release mode so it's not giving any debugging information.

Comment: A sniffer and a debugger are *very* different. Regardless, only foolproof way around a sniffer is SSL

Comment: @ydoow this is what i'm looking for thanks

Comment: @BradleyDotNET thanks for your help and sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To protect your POST data from anonymous debugger, following options may help.

- **Install SSL on your IIS Server.** It depends which version of IIS Server you're using. This link may give a a quick overview. https://www.sslshopper.com/article-installing-an-ssl-certificate-in-windows-server-2008-iis-7.0.html
- **Build your application in RELEASE mode** so it's not giving any debugging information even with debugger connected. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3w7axy17.aspx
- **Encrypt your POST data** is always a proper way to handle your data with security measure. https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/e970bs09(vs.90).aspx

Comment: @ahmed.soli your data is not encrypted so it's exposed in HTTP (not from your app)